# How to calculate the signal period counter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am reading a signal value every few seconds.Plotting the signal results in a clipped fullwave rectified sine wave.I am trying to write a measure, such that everytime the signal completes a period, I should update the counter by 1.How can I do it?

This is how the table looks. This table shows the completion of 1 period.

| DeviceID | TesterID | Value | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 0 | 01.10.2022 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 22 | 500 | 01.10.2022 00:01:00 |
| 1 | 22 | 500 | 01.10.2022 00:01:15 |
| 1 | 22 | 1000 | 01.10.2022 00:02:00 |
| 1 | 22 | 1000 | 01.10.2022 00:02:15 |
| 1 | 22 | 1000 | 01.10.2022 00:02:30 |
| 1 | 22 | 500 | 01.10.2022 00:02:40 |
| 1 | 22 | 500 | 01.10.2022 00:02:42 |
| 1 | 22 | 0 | 01.10.2022 00:02:45 |

[image]

This is how the plot of the signal looks like.For the above image, measure should calculate the counter as 3.
I wrote a measure in DAX, to increase the count by 1, if the signal value goes above 500.But this did not work since I am sampling the data quite fast  which results in reading the same data again(See the column Value for row number 4,5 and 6).

```
 Counter = CALCULATE (COUNTROWS (tableName), FILTER (tableName, tableName[Value]>500))
```

Another way would be to determine the slope of the signal i.e to find that the Value column has crossed 500 in upward slope  and returned to 500 again in the downward slope.Can I calculate slope like this?

Comment: What does that mean: "I am sampling the data quite fast which results in reading the same data again". If you're not able to distinguish new data from old data you'll not be able to count periods.

Comment: I meant that for the row number 4 ,5 and 6, the column Value has 1000. Hence the DAX measure that I have written would not work.

Comment: That's a whole different thing. But where is the measure? Why not share your research effort with us? And looking at all your previous questions, you weren't particularly happy with the answers. What exactly are you expecting now?

Comment: Added the DAX measure.

Comment: Does your sample data table show only one period. It doesn't seem to match your drawing.

Comment: Can you add a counter for each measurement? I think about iterative calculation of zero/non zero neighbor values. If it's not a huge table it can work.

Comment: do you have only 3 values 0/500/1000? Is it possible that your waves have different amplitudes

Comment: @DavidBacci Yes, it shows a single period.

Comment: @Mik It is a huge table,yes these are the only three values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would identify period start with a column as follows:

```
Period Start = 
VAR cursor = tbl[Value] 
VAR val = CALCULATE(SUM(tbl[Value]),OFFSET(1,SUMMARIZE(tbl, tbl[DateTime], tbl[Value]),ORDERBY(tbl[DateTime])), ALLEXCEPT(tbl, tbl[DateTime]))
RETURN
if(cursor ==0 && val>0, 1)
```

I would then have a running total showing which period each row falls into.

```
Period = 
VAR cursor = tbl[DateTime]
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(tbl[Period Start]),   tbl[DateTime] <= cursor, REMOVEFILTERS()  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If have a huge table then I'd add 2 calculated column. The reason is that some calculations would be done before data manipulating.

col 1 :

```
id = 
    RANKX(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            tbl
           ,ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[DeviceID],tbl[TesterID])
        )
       ,[DateTime]
       ,[DateTime]
       ,ASC
       ,Skip
    )
```

col2 :

```
col = 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        tbl[Value]
        ,tbl[id]
        ,[id]-1
        ,tbl[TesterID]
        ,[TesterID]
        ,tbl[DeviceID]
        ,[DeviceID]
    )
    +[Value]
```

The second column will have 2 values of 1500 for each full wave within DeviceID-TesterID.
So, you can try then following trick:

```
 Sumx(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            tbl
            ,tbl[TesterID]
            ,tbl[DeviceID]
        )    
    ,"q"
        ,COUNTROWS( 
            Calculatetable(
                tbl
                ,tbl[col]=1500
            )
        )   
    )
    ,INT([q]/2)
)
```

As a result it should be a number of full waves... I believe )